# ArrayList of ActionListeners cleared when notifyListeners() called

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener

I am trying to write a class that both listens for actions from buttons and notifies another class when one of the buttons is pressed. I have an `ArrayList<ActionListener>` and methods `addActionListener(ActionListener al)`, `removeActionListener(ActionListener al)`, and `notifyActionListeners(ActionEvent ae)`. I print to a separate window whenever I add a listener, and print the size of `actionListeners` as well. It works great and prints that I have 1 actionListener, but then when I try to notify the listeners it says that there are 0 objects in `actionListeners`. I added a `println()` to the `removeActionListener(al)` method to see if it is called, and it never is.
Here's the class:

```
package state;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import driver.GameDriver;
import ui.Button;

public class MainMenu extends Menu {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7130241947836998525L;

    private ArrayList<ActionListener> actionListeners;

    private Button play;
    private Button scores;
    private Button settings;
    private Button help;
    private Button exit;

    public MainMenu() {
        super("Main Menu");
        actionListeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

    }

    @Override
    protected void addComponents() {
        //Irrelevant to Stackexchange
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Object src = arg0.getSource();
        if (src == play) {
        } else if (src == scores) {
        } else if (src == settings) {
        } else if (src == help) {
        } else if (src == exit) {
            ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_FIRST, "exit");

            notifyActionListeners(ae);
        }

    }
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        GameDriver.println("Added Listener:");
        actionListeners.add(al);
        GameDriver.println(actionListeners.size());
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        GameDriver.println("Removed al for some reason");
        actionListeners.remove(al);
    }

    private void notifyActionListeners(ActionEvent ae) {
        GameDriver.println("Sending exit to " + actionListeners.size() + " listeners.");

        for(int i = 0; i < actionListeners.size(); i++) {
            GameDriver.println("Exit sent");
            actionListeners.get(i).actionPerformed(ae);

        }
    }
}
```

Here are the methods that actually reference the instance of `MainMenu`:
1. Initialization

```
protected GameDriver() {
        mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        mainMenu.addActionListener(this);
        debugger = new Debugger();
        println("Size Loader Test...");
        SizeLoader.loadSizes();
        println(SizeLoader.getCurrentSize());
        println("Complete.");
        println("Window Test...");
        window = new Window("Asteroids");
        windowManager = new WindowManager();
//      window.addWindowFocusListener(windowManager);
//      window.addWindowListener(windowManager);
//      window.addWindowStateListener(windowManager);
        window.buildWindow(SizeLoader.getCurrentWidth(), SizeLoader.getCurrentHeight());
        window.add(new MainMenu());
        println("Complete");
        println("Menu Test...");

}
```

And here's the `actionPerformed(ae)`:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        println("Event happened");
        if (e.getSource() == mainMenu) {
            if (e.getActionCommand() == "exit") {
                println("Exiting FR this time...");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why use the AWT gui library? It is years out of date. 2) Don't compare Strings using `==` as that compares for reference equality

Comment: 3) **You're creating more than one MainMenu object**, one you add a listener to and the other you add to window. This looks to be a serious bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: 3) **You're creating more than one MainMenu object**, one you add a listener to and the other you add to window. This looks to be a serious bug.

Instead create only one instance, set its state as needed (add listeners) and add it to the gui.

So change

```
window.add(new MainMenu());
```

To

```
window.add(mainMenu);
```

And again as per my prior comment, don't use == for String equality check but rather the .equals method.